# Maven - Error while processing POM: </dependencies> must match start tag name <project>

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm with a very strange problem.

When I try to run any command from Maven, the following error is showed:

```
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\user\Documents\User\Desenvolvimento\workspace\project\pom.xml: end tag name </dependencies> must match start tag name <proj
ect> from line 1 (position: TEXT seen ...</dependency> -->\r\n\r\n\r\n\t</dependencies>...)
```

Looking to the exception, looks like very simple: "The tag  is missing or  it's out of those tag".

But take a look at my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jmockit.version>0.0.1</jmockit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/junit</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/desenv</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/conf</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java/selenium</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Need Java 5, which is the default since v2.3 of the maven-compiler-plugin. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema1-xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>include.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>com.project.projectws.schema.include</packageName>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.schema1XjcStaleFlag</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema2-xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>include.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>com.project.projectws.schema.include</packageName>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.schema2XjcStaleFlag</staleFile>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/mockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>140</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0-oracle-thin-extras</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-betwixt</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-betwixt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.fckeditor</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>atg.taglib.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jfreechart-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jodreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
            <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I already tried to clean my project (Project > Clean..) and the problem still occurs.
Also tried "mvn clean", "Maven update" and F5 into Eclipse!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try your code in a new workspace. Your pom looks fine to me

Comment: Tossed it into XML Spy and I see balanced tags for everything: project, properties, build, dependencies. (I see a slight difference with my pom.xml files: we have properties/dependencies/build while you have properties/build/dependencies. I am looking at the maven xsd to see if this is significant.) I would suggest running mvn clean from a command line to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Verified that you have a well-formed POM according to  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd. (Were you using maven 4 or 3?)

Comment: The pom code you've posted is correct, except for a missing version of a plugin but no error.

Comment: Is there a malformed parent POM by chance?

Comment: @ctwomey1 I needed to create another workspace... I don't know the reason of this bug, but the same XML worked fine into the new workspace.

thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was malformed parent. (I mistakenly left Git conflict unresolved.)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue and tried too much to resolve this with old version of maven and new version of maven but nothing was work for me..

then I tried with new workspace and i didn't face this issue again.