# Maven Error While Processing POM: [FATAL] Non-parseable POM...PITarget with reserved xml name

Tags: css, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

Anybody has any idea on why this error comes up right after importing a Spring Boot project in Springsource Tool Suite:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\oss-parent\33\oss-parent-33.pom: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserved xml name (position: END_TAG seen ...</profiles>\n\n</project>\n<?xml
```

I looked everywhere and the only similar issues I came across were:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438422/maven-error-while-processing-pom-dependencies-must-match-start-tag-name-p), however, the solution there was to create a new workspace to resolve it. It doesn't work for me.
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538323/non-parseable-pom-spring-boot-maven-project) but this also doesn't work for me.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your xml is malformed

Comment: Update your post with the content of the failing pom (_oss-parent-33.pom_) and the version of maven that you are using. Without that information everyone is just guessing. However, the error message suggests that you have several blank lines (_\n_) in that pom. It might be worth removing all of them to see if it helps. That is easy to do, and it certainly can't do any harm.

Comment: Where's your pom? We can't suggest a solution without it

Comment: Thank you all for replying, your time is very much appreciated! Apparently it had nothing to do with my codebase or POM. After I deleted everything in my ".m2" directory and rebuilt the project everything started working fine. I will just post this as an answer, in case anybody stop by on this post. Thanks again!

Comment: @BalusC - not sure why you down voted my question. I also understand spring and java-ee are not same. The reason I used "spring" and "java-ee" tags was because the error I was getting was in a java-ee project where I am using spring/spring-boot and it is a very common combination. So I can get attention of anybody who has this combination in their project and got this error. What's wrong with that??

Comment: @Gauzy: I didn't downvote. As evidence, I just added one for you. Reply within 5 minutes or edit your question to allow me to undo it. As to Java EE tag, nothing of this all is related to Java EE API. That Spring reuses the WAR project structure doesn't make it a Java EE API problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it had nothing to do with my codebase or POM. After I deleted everything in my ".m2" directory and rebuilt the project it started working fine.

Comment: I just recently created a new workspace and imported my git respo. I ran into the same problem and your solution, deleting directories inside .m2 helped. Path for others C:\Users\<insert username>\.m2 my projects parent was springboot 2.0.4

Comment: I just had to delete the offending artifact (based on my particular error message) from my local repository

Comment: Just delete the offending jars from local repo and it should work

Answer (score 6):

Check whether

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

line repeats in your XML (i.e pom.xml or settings.xml etc)

Comment: that's what did it for me. simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes leading blank line in pom.xml causes Maven to fail with above mentioned error.
After removing leading blank line it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The file is BOM encoded.  There are 2 hex characters before the first < and that is preventing the file from being recognized.  If you use the 32 bit version of NPP you can download the Hex Editor plugin and view (and delete) those 2 characters and save the file.  My situation is similar but the file is being rebuilt so I can't just do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please change you Parent in pom. I used following XML and resolved the issue

```html
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```